# Bash on Windows broke/stuck after moving an empty directory

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

After running the following commands (WARNING: dont run!)

```
mkdir tmp1
mkdir tmp2
mv tmp1/ tmp2/
```

my Bash on Windows terminal got completely stuck while executing the `mv` command and wouldn't complete it. Not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> could interrupt it. When I forcefully closed the bash shell and started up a new one the terminal still seems stuck and won't provide a prompt to enter any commands. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/671) where a deadlock is caused due to the handling of paths with trailing slashes.

It should be fixed in a follow-up update, but for now you'll have to restart Windows before you can use the Bash on Windows shell again.

Moving folders *should* be fine if you avoid trailing slashes:

```
mv tmp1 tmp2
```